# IE11/Windows 10 => Object doesn't support property or method 'includes'

Tags: javascript, cookies, internet-explorer-11, js-cookie

In IE11 on Windows 10, I'm getting `Object doesn't support property or method 'includes' error on Cookie.set('something', null)`. Previously I had `Cookie.remove('something')` and that was giving the same error.

```
  Cookie = require('js-cookie')
  Cookies.set('save_lead', null)
  // used to be:
  // Cookies.remove('save_lead')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: the cookie lib doesn't work in that browser. you might be able to polyfill the `[].includes` method to get it working.

Comment: `Array.prototype.includes` (and `String.prototype.includes` as well) are part of ES2016/ES2015 spec respectively - as soon as you see something has been introduced in ES2015 or later, you know it won't work in Internet Exploder without a polyfill/shim in many cases (as long as it isn't a syntax change, like arrow functions, generator functions, or async/await etc)

Comment: @dandavis js-cookie doesn't use `Array.prototype.includes` internally

Comment: then why would I be getting that error? would something like this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-includes be the best solution?
 Probably not... it's not an actual polyfill

Comment: @FagnerBrack: then it's probably `"".includes`, or the lib is busted.

Comment: The error message says the error happened on line 351 of `raven.js`. That's not the line you show in the image.

Comment: @Barmar no it's definitely the js-cookie code. I found a solution using the package I mentioned above. it allows for a shim. I'm going to answer my own question for future developers w/ same problem

Comment: Is [this](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) the js-cookie library you're using? I couldn't find any use of `includes()` in the source code.

Comment: @Barmar That's correct, there's no `.includes` anywhere. This is definitely a third party code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution to this using the [array-includes](https://github.com/ljharb/array-includes) npm package. At first glance it looks like it just gives you a replacement for calling `arr.includes('foo')` but it also allows for a shim.

From github README:

```
var includes = require('array-includes');
var assert = require('assert');
/* when Array#includes is not present */
delete Array.prototype.includes;
var shimmedIncludes = includes.shim();

assert.equal(shimmedIncludes, includes.getPolyfill());
assert.deepEqual(arr.includes('foo', 1), includes(arr, 'foo', 1));
```

Hope it helps others.